# xmlserializer of attributes and multiple elements

Tags: c#, xml

How can i serialize the following structure using `XmlSerializer`

1. Only 1 instance of `Product`
2. Only 1 instance of `Updates`
3. `Updates` can contain multiple `Item`
4. `Item` can contain multiple `Artifact`

XML:

```
<Product>
    <Cycle Type = "x0446" />
    <Brand Type = "z773g" Include="All" />
    <Updates>
        <Item Name = "Foo">
            <Artifact Kind="6" Action="3" />
        </Item>
        <Item Name = "Bar">
            <Artifact Kind="6" Action="3" />
            <Artifact Kind="53" Action="3" />
        </Item>
    </Updates>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [control xml serialization using attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Use [`XmlAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx) attribute, to change default serialization as element to serialization as attribute. Use [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attribute to serialize lists as a flat sequence of xml elements.

```
public class Product
{
    public Cycle Cycle { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Updates { get; set; }
}

public class Cycle
{
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }    
}

public class Brand
{
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Include")]
    public string Include { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Artifact")]
    public List<Artifact> Artifacts { get; set; }
}

public class Artifact
{
    [XmlAttribute("Kind")]
    public int Kind { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Action")]
    public int Action { get; set; }
}
```

Serialization:

```
Product p = new Product()
{
    Cycle = new Cycle() { Type = "x0446" },
    Brand = new Brand() { Type = "z773g", Include = "All" },
    Updates = new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item() { Name = "Foo", 
                     Artifacts = new List<Artifact>() {
                        new Artifact() { Action = 3, Kind = 6 }
                    }
        },
        new Item() { Name = "Bar", 
                     Artifacts = new List<Artifact>() {
                        new Artifact() { Action = 3, Kind = 6 },
                        new Artifact() { Action = 3, Kind = 53 },
                    }
        }
    }
};

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Product));
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(); // use whatever you need
serializer.Serialize(stream, p);
```

Result:

```
<Product>
    <Cycle Type = "x0446" />
    <Brand Type = "z773g" Include="All" />
    <Updates>
        <Item Name = "Foo">
            <Artifact Kind="6" Action="3" />
        </Item>
        <Item Name = "Bar">
            <Artifact Kind="6" Action="3" />
            <Artifact Kind="53" Action="3" />
        </Item>
    </Updates>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [XmlElement] attribute on array or List properties and XmlSerializer is smart enough to pick up on that and list them in your xml one after another.

**OR**

You can use Visual Studio XML-to-class generator for more complicated structures:
- click start menu in Windows
- click "All Programs"
- find Microsoft Visual Studio  folder and click on it
- click Visual Studio Tools folder
- click Developer Command Prompt...
- let's say your xml is saved in C:\test\Sample.xml
- type "xsd C:\test\Sample.xml /out:C:\test"
  this should inform you a schema was created.
- type "xsd C:\test\Sample.xsd /c /out:C:\test"
  this should inform you a .cs class was created for you, copy it in your solution, possibly with namespace change (or use xsd command parameter for it)
- the classes created may be oddly named and more difficult to work with, use this approach if you have a complicated XML or schema.
- you can extend the generated code with partial classes (look it up), don't modify the generated code directly

--

Here's what direct code (not generated) would look like:

```
public class Product{
    [XmlElement]
    public Cycle Cycle {get;set;}

    [XmlElement]
    public Brand Brand {get;set;}

    [XmlElement]
    public Updates Updates {get;set;}
}

public class Updates{
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public UpdateItem[] Items{get;set;}
}

public class UpdateItem{ 
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name{get;set;} // use [XmlAttribute] in Cycle, Brand and Artifact classes

    [XmlElement("Artifact")]
    public Artifact[] Artifact{get;set;} 
}
//.... etc
```

and here's what the generated code looks like:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class ProductUpdatesItem {

private ProductUpdatesItemArtifact[] artifactField;

private string nameField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Artifact", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public ProductUpdatesItemArtifact[] Artifact {
    get {
        return this.artifactField;
    }
    set {
        this.artifactField = value;
    }
}
```

[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Here some code (one property missed out)

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement("Cycle")]
    public Cycle Cycle { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Updates")]
    public Updates Updates { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        Cycle = new Cycle();
        Updates = new Updates();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Cycle
{
    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Updates
{
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public Updates()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("Artifact", typeof(Artifact))]
    public List<Artifact> Artifacts { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        Artifacts = new List<Artifact>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Artifact
{
    [XmlAttribute("Kind")]
    public int Kind { get; set; }
}
```

Here the code for serialization

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

    private static string SerializeMe(object o)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.Default);

        s.Serialize(writer, o);

        stream.Flush();

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
```

Now here the test code on a console

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product p = new Product();

        p.Cycle.Type = "whatever";

        Item i = new Item();
        i.Artifacts.Add(new Artifact{Kind = 45});

        p.Updates.Items.Add(i);

        Console.WriteLine(SerializeMe(p));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an XML schema (or can generate one) for this structure - my preference is to use XSD.exe to generate the class.